# Explorer.exe DLL Injection

Tags: c++, windows

I have OverlayIcon.dll which provides icon overlay, now i want to inject this dll into explorer.exe or register the dll and restart explorer.exe.

In both the process, i want to know how to restart explorer.exe or refresh it to reflect new overlay icons.

Comment: Hmm, why don't you just ask nicely?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127455%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: When i restart my explorer, Overlay icons are working fine. 
Do i need to embed this dll inside a installer project or my application should inject the dll into explorer.exe everytime ?

Comment: Yes, writing these registry keys and copying the DLL ought to be done by an installer.

Comment: Oops my Installer Project in VS 2012 is not working. I will try in some time.

Just a qq, after adding registry keys how do we restart explorer.exe?